# Canvas / Render Mode / Oculus Rift

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, virtual-reality

I understand by default, `canvas` renders to `screen space`, but we also have the option to render it in `world space`, which is exactly what we need for Oculus Rift. Is this correct?

The attachment shows the details in my inspector, but I get a black screen. Should I remove the `Main Camera` and add a different camera? Are there any subtleties or tricks here, or am I missing something or doing something wrong?

I also get the following messages in my Unity console:

*[CAPI] LibOVR module is located at C:\Windows\system32\LibOVRRT64_0_6.dll*

*[TrackingStateReader] Prediction interval too high: 0.100000 s, clamping at 0.100000 s*

My `Player Settings` are also attached. I am running `Unity 5.1.1f1` and `Oculus 1.7 (SDK 0.6.0.1)`. I would very much appreciate help and guidance...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Depends on how you want your interface to show. Do you want it to be visible to the user regardless the direction you (screen overlay) look in or do you want the UI to live somewhere inside the 3d-enviroment (world space)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marijn. I would like the first option, so that the user would be able to see it anyhow, especially because it is the first scene, offering a selection menu. But I thought Rift only works with World Space. Is that not so? Why do I not see anything at all when I set the Canvas to World Space?

Comment: That does sound strange indeed. When you're in world-space it might have to do with the z-position of the canvas? Maybe your camera is 'behind' the canvas or to close to the camera